# regex : Read number and character from end until space is encountered

Tags: python, regex

I want to divide the line into a date, description, and amount. The last digits are the amount that can contain Cr. I have a line like the following:

```py
Date       Description    Amount
13/03/2021    XYZ ABC 428.00 31,408.37 Cr
17/03/2021    ZOOM.US 111-222-333 WWW.ZOOM.U USD 5.29 841.18
```

The regex that I used is:

```
regex_filter = re.compile(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (.*?) ([\d,]+\.\d{2}) ')**
```

And what I got is:

```
Date - 13/03/2021
Description - XYZ ABC
Amount - 428.00
```

I want the amount to be `31,408.37 Cr` and for the second one amount should be `841.18`. So I want digits and characters up to a space reading from the end.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with anchors and optional group:

```py
^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*?)\s+((?:\d+(?:,\d+)*\.\d{2})(?: Cr)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6Zlb8/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})`: 1st capture group to match date
- `\s+`: 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)`: 2nd capture group to match anything lazily for description
- `\s+`: 1+ whitespaces
- `((?:\d+(?:,\d+)*\.\d{2})(?: Cr)?)`: 3rd capture group to match amount. Inside, we are matching ending `Cr` in an optional non-capture group
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks for helping. The word "Cr" is optional. Although after adding "?", it is still considered compulsory and gives lines that contain Cr and ignores which do not contains Cr. Please suggest something regarding this,

Comment: No that's not correct. Take a look at linked demo in my answer. It is matching both the lines: one with ending `Cr` and other without `Cr`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ttp template to parse your data other than Regex. I did the following sample to parse your data. It will work if your 'Date' and 'Amount' values (with or without 'CR') has similar template.

```
from ttp import ttp
import json

data_to_parse = """
Date       Description    Amount
13/03/2021    XYZ ABC 428.00 31,408.37 Cr
17/03/2021    ZOOM.US 111-222-333 WWW.ZOOM.U USD 5.29 841.18
"""

ttp_template = """
<group name="DATA">
{{Date}}    {{desc1}} {{desc2}} {{desc3}} {{Amount}} {{Amout_CR}}
</group>
<group name="DATA">
{{Date}}    {{desc1}} {{desc2}} {{desc3}} {{desc4}} {{desc5}} {{Amount}}
</group>
"""

parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()

# print result in JSON format
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
#print(results)

#converting str to json. 
result = json.loads(results)

#print(results)
line_desc = ""
k = False #This is an indicator if the 'description' consists of how many words is not known. 
for i in result[0]["DATA"]:
    
    for desc in i.keys():
        if 'desc' in desc:
            line_desc += i[desc] + " "
            if k == True:
                line_desc = "" # description field will be empty as it starts to new line. 
                k = False
                continue
            
    k = True

    # print(i[f'desc{j}'])

    if 'Amout_CR' in i:
        print(f"""
        Date : {i['Date']}
        Description: {line_desc}
        Amount : {i['Amount'] + ' ' + i['Amout_CR']}""")
    else:
        print(f"""
        Date : {i['Date']}
        Description: {line_desc}
        Amount : {i['Amount']}""")
```

See the output after the program runs:

[image]

See the following parsed data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/42Gv7e/1)):

```py
import re

txt = """
Date       Description    Amount
13/03/2021    XYZ ABC 428.00 31,408.37 Cr
17/03/2021    ZOOM.US 111-222-333 WWW.ZOOM.U USD 5.29 841.18
"""

r = re.compile(r"^(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(.*)\s+([\d,.]+(?:\s*Cr)?)$", flags=re.M)

out = [
    {"Date": date, "Description": desc, "Amount": amount}
    for date, desc, amount in r.findall(txt)
]
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "Date": "13/03/2021",
        "Description": "XYZ ABC 428.00",
        "Amount": "31,408.37 Cr",
    },
    {
        "Date": "17/03/2021",
        "Description": "ZOOM.US 111-222-333 WWW.ZOOM.U USD 5.29",
        "Amount": "841.18",
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```py
import re
res = []

filepath = r'path_to_file'
rx = re.compile(r'^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*?)\s+(\d[\d,]*\.\d{2}(?:\s+Cr)?)$')

with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = rx.search(line.strip())
        if m:
            res.append(m.groups())

print(res)
```

The regex is

```
^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*?)\s+(\d[\d,]*\.\d{2}(?: Cr)?)$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` - Group 1: date like pattern
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d[\d,]*\.\d{2}(?: Cr)?)` - Group 3: a number with 2 digits after decimal separator and an optional sequence of a space + `Cr`.
- `$` - end of string.
  See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ErEzHX/1)

Answer (score 0):

Without `Cr`
Regex would be `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*)\s+([.,\d]+)\s+([.,\d]+)`

With `Cr`
Regex would be `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*)\s+([.,\d]+)\s+([.,\d]+.*)`

Tip please don't forget to add `g` (global flag) to parse whole text in one go.

Sample python code:

```
import re

regex = r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*)\s+([.,\d]+)\s+([.,\d]+.*)"

test_str = ("Date       Description    Amount\n"
    "13/03/2021    XYZ ABC 428.00 31,408.37 Cr\n"
    "17/03/2021    ZOOM.US 111-222-333 WWW.ZOOM.U USD 5.29 841.18")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```